# Convert from one archive type to another using CLI

Tags: 14.04, command-line, archive, file-roller

If a particular archive type has to be converted into another format (eg - `tar.gz` to `zip`), then one can open the archive using `file-roller` and go to -

> Archive -> Save As -> (select the extension) -> Save

Also, in this method, *Other Options* can be used to set a password for the `zip` file, which is not possible in case of `tar.gz` files using `file-roller`.

How can the above steps be performed using the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic Shell commands:

```
$ cd $HOME
$ mkdir tempdir
$ cd tempdir
$ tar -zxvf ../archive.tar.gz
```

At this point you have a copy of the contents of `archive.tar.gz` in $HOME/tempdir/

```
$ zip -rmp password ../archive.zip *
```

... will create a zip archive from the contents of tempdir/ and then remove the files added. I presume it still does; `use standard (weak) PKZip 2.0 encryption` as stated for the `-e` option - which doesn't take the password, but prompts for it instead.

Make SURE / VERIFY you're still in tempdir/

```
$ pwd
.../tempdir
```

If there is ANYTHING else than "/tempdir" at the end above,
then **DO NOT continue** with what comes next, here:

```
$ rm -rf *  
$ cd ..
$ rmdir tempdir
```

All the above might be possible with a pipe too, as in:

```
$ tar -zxvf ./archive.tar.gz - | zip -p password - ./archive.zip
```

... I see no reason to try it out though - due to the **weak** encryption and possible problems with how zip handles special files, links and whatnot.

If you want real encryption, look into `gnupg` and related utilities instead.

`man tar`, `man zip`, `zip --help`, `zip -h2 | less`, `tar --help | less` may hold information vital to the above, especially the piped conversion which I have not tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [tar-to-zip](https://github.com/coderaiser/node-tar-to-zip) for this purpose. All you need to do is:

Install node.js with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) if you do not have it.

And then install `tar-to-zip` with:

```
npm i tar-to-zip -g
```

And use it with:

```
tar2zip hello.tar.gz
```

It will show percents of operation progress and create file `hello.zip` in the same directory.

Pipes could be used as well:

```
cat hello.tar.gz | tar2zip > hello.zip
```

Unfortunately there is no way to set a password.